# what's the byte length for HMAC-SHA-1 signature?

Tags: security

I am wondeirng what's the output length for HMAC-SHA-1 alogorthm? if using Base64 encoding, what's the final length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

20 raw bytes, so ceil(20/3)*4 = 28 bytes as base64.

Answer (score 3):

The result of any [HMAC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) is the output from the choosen digest:

> To compute HMAC over the data `text' we perform
>
> ```
>                H(K XOR opad, H(K XOR ipad, text))
> ```

Where you want H to be [SHA-1](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-2/fips180-2withchangenotice.pdf). So the length of a HMAC-SHA-1 is the same as the length of a SHA-1 that is 160 bits or 20 bytes.

The [Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) encoding expands groups of 3 bytes into 4. So the resulting size will be ceiling(20/3)×4 = 28 characters. Also note that due to padding the last character will *always* be "=".

Comment: Note: Base64 for URI (e.g JWT) does not use trailing "="